# Status Message On Discord Bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Does it matter where the code for the status message goes? I keep getting  an error in cmd when test like
setActivity
^^^^^
it those that above tried placing it about in the script.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: To answer your question. No it doesn't matter where you execute your status code as long as it's correct. If you try to use a command to change your status you may notice some delay between execution and display of the status change.

Answer (score 0):

you should have defined a `client` object using the `const client = new Discord.Client();` method.

Then have it wait until the bot is ready like this:

```js
 client.once('ready', async () => {})
```

now you can set the activity using `client.user.setActivity('doin' stuff')`

so putting it all together it would look like:

```js
client.once('ready', async () => {
   client.user.setActivity('doin stuff');
});
```

just make sure the `client` is defined

Comment: i did not know that should do it in `client.once('ready', async () => {})` putting it the that would help. Thanks alot

Comment: like in that same line i thought it was something separate.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is:

```
client.on('ready', async () => {
        client.user.setActivity('YOUR STATUS', {
            type: 'LISTENING'
        });
}
```

The type can be LISTENING, WATCHING, COMPETING, or PLAYING. You choose which one you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I do my status the following way.

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  // Code here
});
```

To fill in the gaps add this

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  client.user.setActivity(`My Activity Here`);
  client.user.setStatus("dnd"); // Sets do not disturb on, can be set to online or idle, etc
  console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
});
```